# Enabling cgroup cpu real-time runtime in ubuntu kernel

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, real-time

I am trying to use real-time scheduling in a docker container running on Ubuntu 18.04.

I have already installed a realtime kernel following the method given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669724/install-rt-linux-patch-for-ubuntu). I have selected kernel version 5.2.9 and its associated rt patch.

The output of `uname -a` confirms that the realtime kernel is well installed and running:

```
Linux myLaptop 5.2.9-rt3 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT ...
```

To run my container I issue the following command:

```
docker run --cpu-rt-runtime=95000 \
    --ulimit rtprio=99 \
    --ulimit memlock=102400 \
    --cap-add=sys_nice \
    --privileged \
    -it \
    myimage:latest
```

However, the output I got is:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Your kernel does not support cgroup cpu real-time runtime.
```

I have seen that this can be linked to the missing `CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED` as detailed in the issue [here](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/937). Indeed if I run the script provided at [this page](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/check-config.sh) to check the kernel compatibility with Docker I get:

```
- CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED: missing
```

Which seems to confirm that Docker is using this for realtime scheduling but is not provided in the kernel, although patched to be realtime.

From there, I tried to find a solution in vain. I am not well versed in kernel configurations to know if I need to compile it with a specific option, and which one to choose, to add the missing `CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED`.

Thanks a lot in advance for recommendations and help.

Comment: Same problem in Fedora Server 31 using 5.0.14-300.rt9.1.fc30.ccrma.x86_64+rt Kernel. The check-config.sh script reports "CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED: missing", and "docker run -it --cpu-rt-runtime=950000 --ulimit rtprio=99 --cap-add=sys_nice debian:jessie" fails with "docker: Error response from daemon: Your kernel does not support cgroup cpu real-time runtime."

Answer (score 3):

When talking about real-time Linux there are different approaches ranging from single kernel approaches (like [`PREEMPT_RT`](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/start)) to [dual-kernel approaches](https://linuxgizmos.com/real-time-linux-explained/) (such as [Xenomai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenomai)). You can use real-time capable Dockers in combination with all of them (clearly the kernel of your host machine has to match) to produce real-time capable systems but the approaches differ. **In your case you are mixing up two different approaches: You installed `PREEMPT_RT` while following a guide for [control groups](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#configure-the-realtime-scheduler) which are incompatible with `PREEMPT_RT`.**

---

By **default** the Linux kernel can be compiled with different levels of preempt-ability (see e.g. [Reghenzani et al. - "The real-time Linux kernel: a Survey on PREEMPT_RT"](https://re.public.polimi.it/retrieve/handle/11311/1076057/344112/paper.pdf#page=8)):

- `PREEMPT_NONE` has no way of forced preemption
- `PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY` where preemption is possible in some locations in order to reduce latency
- `PREEMPT` where preemption can occur in any part of the kernel (excluding [spinlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) and other critical sections)

These can be combined with the feature of [control groups (`cgroups` for short)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html) by setting [`CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED=y` during kernel compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56189862/9938686), which reserves a certain fraction of CPU-time for processes of a certain (user-defined) group.

**`PREEMPT_RT`** developed from `PREEMPT` and is a set of patches that aims at making the kernel fully preemptible, even in critical sections (`PREEMPT_RT_FULL`). For this purpose e.g. [spinlocks are largely replaced by mutexes](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/documentation/technical_details/sleeping_spinlocks).
As of 2021 it is being [slowly merged into the mainline](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=PREEMPT-RT-Locking-In-Linux-515) and will be available to the general public without the need to patch the kernel. As stated [here](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/documentation/known_limitations) `PREEMPT_RT` currently can't be compiled with the `CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED` and therefore can't be used with control groups (see [here for a comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62932857/difference-between-config-rt-group-sched-and-preempt-rt)). From what I have read this is due to [high latency spikes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_for_real_time/8/html-single/optimizing_rhel_8_for_real_time_for_low_latency_operation/index#further_considerations), something that I have already observed with control groups by means of [`cyclicytest`s](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/documentation/howto/tools/cyclictest/start).

This means you can **either** compile your kernel (see the [Ubuntu manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/install.en.pdf#page=98) for details)

- Without `PREEMPT_RT` but with `CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED` (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56189710/9938686) for details) and follow the [Docker guide on real-time with control groups](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#configure-the-realtime-scheduler) as well as my post [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70597953/9938686). From my experience this has though quite high latency spikes, something not desirable for real-time system where the worst-case latency is much more important than the average latency.
- With **`PREEMPT_RT` without `CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED`** (which can also be installed from a Debian package such as [this one](https://packages.debian.org/buster/linux-image-rt-amd64)). In this case it is sufficient to execute the Docker with the options **`--privileged --net=host`**, or the Docker-compose equivalent `privileged: true network_mode: host`. Then **any process from inside the Docker can set real-time priorities `rtprio`** (e.g. by calling [`::pthread_setschedparam`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_getschedparam.3.html) from inside the code or by using [`chrt`](https://askubuntu.com/a/51285) from the command line).

  In case you are [not using the `root` as user inside the Docker](https://medium.com/jobteaser-dev-team/docker-user-best-practices-a8d2ca5205f4) you furthermore will have to have give yourself a name of a user that belongs to a group with **real-time privileges on your host computer** (see `$ ulimit -r`). This can be done by configuring the [PAM limits](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Sound/How_to_Enable_Realtime_for_Multimedia_Applications) (`/etc/security/limits.conf` file) accordingly (as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/487602/linux-etc-security-limits-conf-explanation)) by copying the section of the `@realtime` user group and creating a new group (e.g. `@some_group`) or adding the user (e.g. `some_user`) directly:

  ```
  @some_group     soft    rtprio          99
  @some_group     soft    priority        99
  @some_group     hard    rtprio          99
  @some_group     hard    priority        99
  ```

  In this context `rtprio` is the maximum real-time priority allowed for non-privileged processes. The `hard` limit is the real limit to which the `soft` limit can be set to. The `hard` limits are set by the super-user and enforce by the kernel. The user cannot raise his code to run with a higher priority than the `hard` limit. The `soft` limit on the other hand is the default value limited by the `hard` limit. For more information see e.g. [here](https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf).

I use latter option for real-time capable robotic applications and could not observe any differences in latency between with and without the Docker. You can find a [guide on how to set up `PREEMPT_RT` and automated scripts for building it on my Github](https://github.com/2b-t/docker-realtime).